# Tool for simplifying/optimizing logic?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Usually I would let the compiler do it's magic of optimizing complicated logical expressions, however, in this case the compiler I have to use is not very good at this (basically all it can do is to replaced things like /64 with bit-shifts and %512 with bitwise-and).

Is there any tool available that can analyze and provide optimized versions of expressions, (i.e. the same way good optimizing compilers do)?

e.g. I would like to optimize the following:

```
int w = 2 - z/2;

int y0 = y + (((v % 512) / 64) / 4) * 8           + ((v / 512) / mb)*16;
int x0 = x + (((v % 512) / 64) % 4) * 8 * (w - 1) + ((v / 512) % mb)*8 * w;

int i = x0 * (w ^ 3) * 2 + y0 * mb * 16 * 2 + (2*z - 3) * (z/2);
```

Comment: what about basic math? `x / 64 / 4 = x / (64*4) = x / 256` ;)

Comment: Try `unsigned` types, and say `const`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: The optimizer handles such basic things, I'm more referring to the complicated logic with ^. -3 *2 etc...

Comment: Plugging them in wolfram alpha (with some syntax changes) often works great.

Comment: I'd do it by hand anyway. It's good exercise if you have time for it. With some help from wolfram, to verify the results, maybe.

Comment: Oh, does `w ^ 3` really do what you intend?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I am doing it by hand :), it just got me thinking whether there is a faster way.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes it does, since w is either 1 or 2.

Comment: @PaulR: It's not about whether it's hard or not, it's about whether there is a better way, I could write it in assembler right away as well, doesn't mean I should if I don't have to.

Comment: @ronag: since the code sucks pretty badly in its present form it would be a good idea to improve it both for the sake of performance and for the sake of performance. That's really a job for a human.

Comment: Beyond the obvious, the only thing I found here was that `((v % 512) / 64) % 4)` (take the lowest 9 bits, throw the first 6 away, then throw the highest away) can be simplified to `(v >> 6) & 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a test:

```
typedef int MyInt; // or unsigned int

MyInt get(MyInt x, MyInt y, MyInt z, MyInt v, MyInt mb)
{
    MyInt w = 2 - z/2;

    MyInt y0 = y + (((v % 512) / 64) / 4) * 8           + ((v / 512) / mb)*16;
    MyInt x0 = x + (((v % 512) / 64) % 4) * 8 * (w - 1) + ((v / 512) % mb)*8 * w;

    MyInt i = x0 * (w ^ 3) * 2 + y0 * mb * 16 * 2 + (2*z - 3) * (z/2);

    return i;
}
```

I compiled with GCC 4.7.0 with `-O3`.

With `int`:

```
.LFB0:
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        movq    %r12, -24(%rsp)
.LCFI0:
        movl    %edx, %r12d
        sarl    $31, %eax
        shrl    $31, %r12d
        movq    %r13, -16(%rsp)
        shrl    $23, %eax
        addl    %edx, %r12d
        movq    %rbx, -40(%rsp)
        leal    (%rcx,%rax), %r9d
        movl    %r12d, %r11d
        movq    %r14, -8(%rsp)
        sarl    %r11d
        movq    %rbp, -32(%rsp)
.LCFI1:
        movl    %edx, %ebp
        andl    $511, %r9d
        negl    %r11d
        subl    %eax, %r9d
        leal    511(%rcx), %eax
        testl   %ecx, %ecx
        leal    2(%r11), %r13d
        leal    63(%r9), %ebx
        cmovns  %ecx, %eax
        sarl    $9, %eax
        movl    %r13d, %r14d
        xorl    $3, %r14d
        movl    %eax, %edx
        testl   %r9d, %r9d
        cmovns  %r9d, %ebx
        sarl    $31, %edx
        addl    $1, %r11d
        idivl   %r8d
        movl    %ebx, %r10d
        sarl    $31, %ebx
        shrl    $30, %ebx
        sarl    $6, %r10d
        addl    %ebx, %r10d
        andl    $3, %r10d
        subl    %ebx, %r10d
        movq    -40(%rsp), %rbx
        sall    $3, %r10d
        sall    $3, %edx
        imull   %r11d, %r10d
        imull   %r13d, %edx
        movq    -16(%rsp), %r13
        addl    %edi, %r10d
        addl    %edx, %r10d
        leal    255(%r9), %edx
        imull   %r10d, %r14d
        testl   %r9d, %r9d
        cmovs   %edx, %r9d
        sall    $4, %eax
        sarl    %r12d
        sarl    $8, %r9d
        leal    (%rsi,%r9,8), %ecx
        addl    %eax, %ecx
        leal    -3(%rbp,%rbp), %eax
        movq    -32(%rsp), %rbp
        imull   %r8d, %ecx
        imull   %r12d, %eax
        movq    -24(%rsp), %r12
        sall    $4, %ecx
        addl    %r14d, %ecx
        movq    -8(%rsp), %r14
        leal    (%rax,%rcx,2), %eax
        ret
```

With `unsigned int`:

```
.LFB0:
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        movq    %rbp, -16(%rsp)
        movl    %edx, %r11d
.LCFI0:
        movl    %edx, %ebp
        shrl    $9, %eax
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        divl    %r8d
        movq    %r12, -8(%rsp)
.LCFI1:
        movl    %ecx, %r12d
        shrl    %r11d
        andl    $511, %r12d
        movq    %rbx, -24(%rsp)
.LCFI2:
        movl    $2, %r10d
        movl    %r12d, %r9d
        movl    $1, %ebx
        subl    %r11d, %r10d
        shrl    $6, %r9d
        subl    %r11d, %ebx
        shrl    $8, %r12d
        andl    $3, %r9d
        sall    $4, %r8d
        imull   %ebx, %r9d
        leal    (%r12,%rax,2), %eax
        movq    -24(%rsp), %rbx
        imull   %r10d, %edx
        xorl    $3, %r10d
        movq    -8(%rsp), %r12
        leal    (%rsi,%rax,8), %eax
        addl    %edx, %r9d
        leal    (%rdi,%r9,8), %edi
        imull   %eax, %r8d
        leal    -3(%rbp,%rbp), %eax
        movq    -16(%rsp), %rbp
        imull   %r10d, %edi
        imull   %r11d, %eax
        addl    %edi, %r8d
        leal    (%rax,%r8,2), %eax
        ret
```

"Optimizing" further by folding constants manually has (predictably) no further effect.

Comment: Thanks, that's one step in the right direction, would be nice though if one could "disassembly" to optimized assembly, to make it more readable.

Comment: Ultimately, 25 CPU instructions for the computation of this value is pretty decent, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

When I want optimizations, I tend to check what Clang generates as LLVM IR. It's more readable (I find) than pure assembly.

```
int foo(int v, int mb, int x, int y, int z) {
  int w = 2 - z/2;

  // When you have specific constraints, tell the optimizer about it !
  if (w < 0 || w > 2) { return 0; }

  int y0 = y + (((v % 512) / 64) / 4) * 8           + ((v / 512) / mb)*16;
  int x0 = x + (((v % 512) / 64) % 4) * 8 * (w - 1) + ((v / 512) % mb)*8 * w;

  int i = x0 * (w ^ 3) * 2 + y0 * mb * 16 * 2 + (2*z - 3) * (z/2);

  return i;
}
```

Is transformed into:

```
define i32 @foo(i32 %v, i32 %mb, i32 %x, i32 %y, i32 %z) nounwind uwtable readnone {
  %1 = sdiv i32 %z, 2
  %2 = sub nsw i32 2, %1
  %3 = icmp slt i32 %2, 0
  %4 = icmp slt i32 %z, -1
  %or.cond = or i1 %3, %4
  br i1 %or.cond, label %31, label %5

; <label>:5                                       ; preds = %0
  %6 = srem i32 %v, 512
  %7 = sdiv i32 %6, 64
  %8 = sdiv i32 %6, 256
  %9 = shl i32 %8, 3
  %10 = sdiv i32 %v, 512
  %11 = sdiv i32 %10, %mb
  %12 = shl i32 %11, 4
  %13 = add i32 %9, %y
  %14 = add i32 %13, %12
  %15 = srem i32 %7, 4
  %16 = add nsw i32 %2, -1
  %17 = mul i32 %16, %15
  %18 = srem i32 %10, %mb
  %19 = mul i32 %2, %18
  %tmp = add i32 %19, %17
  %tmp2 = shl i32 %tmp, 3
  %20 = add nsw i32 %tmp2, %x
  %21 = shl i32 %2, 1
  %22 = xor i32 %21, 6
  %23 = mul i32 %22, %20
  %24 = shl i32 %mb, 5
  %25 = mul i32 %24, %14
  %26 = shl i32 %z, 1
  %27 = add nsw i32 %26, -3
  %28 = mul nsw i32 %1, %27
  %29 = add i32 %25, %28
  %30 = add i32 %29, %23
  br label %31

; <label>:31                                      ; preds = %5, %0
  %.0 = phi i32 [ %30, %5 ], [ 0, %0 ]
  ret i32 %.0
}
```

I do not know whether it is optimal, but it certainly is relatively readable.

It would be great if you could indicate all your constraints on the input (all five of them if necessary) because the optimizer might be able to use them.